# reading a returned Promise value

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to Promises in serverside (Node js). Here is my question

I have code in FileA.js

```
    incoming_form = client_services.pullForm('vsl_video1.mp4');
     incoming_form.resolve().then(function(results) {
      return console.log(results);
    });
```

The incoming_form returns a Promise something like this in FileB.js

```
    incoming_form () {
     return Promise (function (resp, rej) {
        var myArray = ['fudge', 'fgfdgdf'];
          return resp(myArray);
      });
    }
```

How can I read my 'myArray' value in FileA.js? when I ran my FileA.js, I am getting this error
*TypeError: incoming_form.resolve is not a function*

Comment: if you have a promise object, you do not need to call .resolve() just do promiseObj,then( function.. )

Comment: try `return resp(myArray);` in incomming_form

Comment: There's so many examples of working with promises out there on the web.

Comment: Why do you use `Promise` in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the value of a promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: Cl3m, sorry it was returning rest(myArray) as you stated, but I am getting this error "TypeError: incoming_form.resolve is not a function<br> " when I do              incoming_form.resolve().then(function(results) {
          return console.log(results);
        });

Comment: Tresdin, The incoming_form() is returned by some one else already. I just have to use it and see how I can print the array from the returned Promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the internal mechanisms by which `Promise` objects operate. This is how your code should look:

```
function incoming_form () {
 return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(['fudge', 'fgfdgdf']);      
  });
}

incoming_form().then(function(results){
    console.log ("Results" + results");
})
```

Note how the promise resolves *internally*, as opposed in a function call. Whenever a promise resolves, operation (and the arguments that the promise resolves with, in this case an array) is deferred to the closest subsequent `then()` clause.

Hope this clears some things up!

Answer (score 1):

Use response.json() and then to return the value from promise object.

```
    fetch('http://localhost:3100/comments')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(comments => console.log(comments));
```