# Get number of records saved in Indexed DB using Dexie Js

Tags: angular, indexeddb, dexie

I am new to Angular and JS. Right now I am writing code to save data to Indexed db and I want to show number of records which are pending (in indexed db) on navigation bar, I am not able to get the total number of records saved to Indexed DB.

I am using the codes below to get the count, but it is only usable inside the arrow function/callback function. I have tried assigning it to global variable, but it returns null.

Here is the code, I want to utilize these methods and return the number of records which exists in the IDB.

```
 private countIDBRecords() {
    this.db.myTableName.toCollection().count( (count: string) => {
      
      console.log(count + " records in total");  // this returns correct value, but i cannot use 'count' outside this function
  
      this.totalRecords = count;
  });  

  console.log(this.totalRecords); //return null

}
```

Comment: Maybe `this` inside the arrow function is local to the function and hides the component's `this`. What if you say `that = this;` outside of the `private` method, and inside the arrow function say `that.totalRecords = count;`?

Comment: Cannot find name 'that'.ts(2304)

Comment: Can you post a simple app on Stackblitz that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the count was returning promise function along with the value which I needed. So, first I found this answer : [Using Getter and Setter to assign value to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74924580/7733050)

Later, I found out that using a simple async and await would resolve my problem,

```
async countIDBRecords() {
    var data = await this.db.tableName.count();
    console.log('Total records in tableName: ',data);
  }
```