# ReactJS actions not loading data through ajax call

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement wherein I need to load the data through an ajax call to server and then pass on the data to reducer to render my page through props.

But I see the data in the ajax call is being shown as undefined.

```
function getInitData(url) {
    axios({url: url, timeout: 20000, method: 'get', responseType: 'json'})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.results)//--DATA DISPLAYED
        return response.data.results
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        console.error(response.data);
    })
}

let formActions = {
    loadInitJSONSchema: function(formSchema) {
        let dataLoaded = getInitData('/startInterview')
        console.log(dataLoaded);//--DATA DISPLAYED as UNDEFINED
        return {type: 'LOAD_INIT_JSON_SCHEMA', formSchema: dataLoaded}
    }

}
```

I dont know why my data displayed as undefined in my actual method may be it is because of the asynchrnous call?? If so how do I load my data in actions??

Please find the complete code at the [URL](https://github.com/yvsivateja/ReactJSApplications/blob/one/React-json-render/actions/formActions.js)

Comment: You would return a promise from `getInitData` then use `getInitData.then()`

Comment: Once you start a promise, the only way for anyone to get the fulfilled values is inside a `.then()` callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the value of a promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: @AndyRay,@CarlMarkham I have used then to return my actual response right??

Answer (score 1):

It's promises all the way down.

A jQuery example: `jQuery('body')` does *not* return the body element. It returns a jQuery collection. `jQuery('body').css('background', 'red');` also returns a jQuery collection. It's collections all the way down.

`axios.get().then(function(response) { return response; })` does *not* return response. It returns a promise.

First, change this, to return the promise:

```
function getInitData(url) {
    return axios...
```

Then change your function:

```
loadInitJSONSchema: function(formSchema) {
    return getInitData('/startInterview').then(function(data) {
        return {type: 'LOAD_INIT_JSON_SCHEMA', formSchema: data}
    })
```

Then anyone who uses `loadInitJSONSchema` gets the promise and gets the value in a `.then()`.

`loadInitJSONSchema(schema).then(function(result) { ... do something with result })`

It's promises all the way down.

This flow is **asynchronous**. With `var something = axios.get().then(function(response) { return response; })` the code is evaluated in place and the program keeps going. The `.then()` callback happens **at a later time, long after the current function has finished executing.**

Comment: I've changed it to function getInitData(url) {
    return axios.get(url)
} and loadInit.. as per given above... But I get an error saying Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Yup. Use something like https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk to let you return promises from your redux action creators, where the promise fulfils with a redux action. That's unrelated to this question.