# How to export module asynchronously in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I cannot export a module that I wrote it myself in an asynchronous way.

```
const glob = require('glob');

var confFiles;

glob("conf/**/*.conf", function (er, files) {
    confFiles = files;
});

module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(confFiles);
});
```

This is the module itself and I want to access `confFiles` in other files but the point is that glob is not asynchronous and I'm having trouble finding my way to solve it.

Comment: Are you trying to lazily read configuration files?

Comment: I'm not sure what Lazily reading means, I'm quite new to Nodejs

Comment: Lazily means that reading the configuration file only happens when the code calls for it, and not beforehand.

Comment: Not actually, I want it to be ready before everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd export a `load` method instead:

```
// conf.js
const glob = require('glob')

module.exports.load = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  glob('conf/**/*.conf', function (err, files) {
    if (err) return reject(err)

    resolve(files)
  })
})
```

And then in userland:

```
// index.js
const conf = require('./conf.js')

conf.load()
  .then(files => {
    console.log(files)
  })
```

Or, you can just use [`globe.sync`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options) instead and avoid dealing with async code entirely:

```
// conf.js
const glob = require('glob')

module.exports = glob.sync('conf/**/*.conf')
```

And then in userland:

```
// index.js
const files = require('./conf.js')
console.log(files)
```

Just keep in mind that `globe.sync` is a [blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) operation.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve when the callback calls back:

```
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  glob("conf/**/*.conf", function (err, files) {
   if(err) reject(err) else resolve(files);
  });
}));
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
 const glob = require("glob");
 const { promisify } = require("util");

module.exports = promisify(glob)("conf/**/*.conf");
```

Comment: How should I use it when I require it? It says like this `Promise { <pending> }` when I try to use it.

Comment: @shadow4Kill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise

Comment: I read it before but didn't get my answer. Thanks for your answer btw.