# unable to pull data from browser.storage.local.get

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage

trying to implement options page for a firefox addon/extension version 64.0. I am using `browser.storage.local.se`t to store data. but when I use `browser.storage.local.get` to pull the data, the result is `<unavailable>` on the console log.

the following is the function i run in my `options.js` file (i entered `njnj` on the form field `gateway` and hit the submit button)

```
function saveOptions(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("you are here")
  console.log(document.querySelector("#gateway").value)
  browser.storage.local.set({
  "gateway": document.querySelector("#gateway").value  });
  console.log(browser.storage.local.get("gateway"))
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

my actual output in the console log is as follows :

```
you are here                                         options.js:4:3
njnj                                                options.js:5:3
<unavailable>                                       options.js:8:3
```

Comment: my expected output should be to get 'njnj' back as the value for "gateway", since that is what I just set it to.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I did figure out partly why the above code is not working. the problem is that browser.storage.local.get() returns a 'promise' in javascript (I dont actually know what it means yet). So you have to have a code that will actually retrieve the answer/saved value from this 'promise'. I will give you an example on how to retrieve the value:

```
// first save a key value pair into storage
browser.storage.local.set({"key": 'value'})

// to retrieve this value, first declare a new variable
var savedvalue = "zero"

// retrieve the 'promise' of key value pair, then run the associated function to get
//the savedvalue and set it equal to previously declared variable. 
browser.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {savedvalue = result.key});

// now, when you call savedvalue (even outside the function above), it will return 'value'
console.log(savedvalue)

output>> value
```

Comment: Edit by an anonymous user: *`function(result) {savedvalue = result.key});`  <== Dik: Should probably be: `result.value` or something*.

Comment: This construct isn't quite correct: the code should be 
`browser.storage.local.get('key').then(
        function (result) {
            console.log(result.key);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // error code
        });`
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-promise

Answer (score 0):

You could use async function and await, like this

```
async function saveOptions(e) {

  e.preventDefault();      
  await browser.storage.local.set(
    { "gateway": document.querySelector("#gateway").value }
  );
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", async saveOptions);
```

You don't need to pass the 'e' to the function, you're not doing anything with it.
You could also refactor it this way, if the mood took you

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener( "submit", async ()=> {
    e.preventDefault();      
    await browser.storage.local.set(
      { "gateway": document.querySelector("#gateway").value }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is really about how to get/handle the value of a Promise in async Javascript (which the `browser.storage.local.get()` method is).

```js
browser.storage.local.get('gateway').then(
        function (result) {
            // code goes here
            console.log(result.gateway);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // error code
        });
```

see [How can I access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-promise)