# What's the correct way to pause the entire script execution contingent on an asynchronous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A lot of my script is contingent on information first read from a .JSON file using `fetch()` and `.json()` so it's asynchronous. I need to delay the execution of the rest of my script until those functions finish, without sticking the rest of my code in a huge `.then()` or function block or something. I've done some searching around but I can't really find what I'm looking for.

```
let config;

fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("../config.json"))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => config = json);

console.log(config);
// REST OF SCRIPT
```

It should log the config JSON object or the promise but, obviously, it only returns undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add another `then`

Comment: Or use `async`/`await`

Comment: ^ That won't work outside of a function I think, but yeah overall it's a better choice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: yeah no way around a giant function block around ypur code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one thread to work with, so there's no getting around the fact that you need to perform the async fetch of you config and *then* get on with the rest of your program. Most javascript is event driven, so this isn't typically a big issue. You can write in a style where the primary entrance to your code is a `main()` function, then you can just call it with the config after it's fetched:

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("../config.json"))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(main);

function main(config){
  // do stuff


}
```

Any substantially large code-base will be refactored into smaller functions anyway, so ideally your `main` function should not really be that large to begin with.

Comment: Huh. I was kinda hesitant just to wrap my entire script in a ```then``` but separating it into a ```main()``` like in other languages is a really good way to look at it. Thanks!

Also, when you do a ```then(function);``` does it just call that function and pass the promised value to that function as an argument?

Comment: Yes. `then()` takes a function. So you could do `then(config => main(config))`, but that just adds a level of indirection in this case since `main` is already a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `config` is being read before the request comes back. You can add another `then` clause:

```
let config;

fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("../config.json"))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => config = json)
  .then(() => {
     console.log(config);
   });
```

Comment: I'd like to access the ```config``` object in various places throughout the rest of the script, so I don't really want to put the entire rest of the script in one ```then``` clause if it can be helped.

Comment: You're going to have to do this one way or another, since it's "async"  If you want to "simulate" it outside of a "then" you can use `async` and `await` but keep in mind it's merely simulating the above, it's syntax sugar.

Comment: It can't be helped. It's promises all the way down.

Comment: you can write a promise-returning wrapper called getConfig() that caches the config the first time, if you're worried about performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("../config.json"))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(config => console.log(config));
```

Or:

```
const response = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("../config.json"));
const config = await response.json();
config => console.log(config)
```

Comment: You have to `await response.json()` too.

Comment: True, i **fixed** the answer