# How to get the return value of a javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am struggling to understand how to get the value of a promise within Javascript to be able to check whether it is true or false.

```
let valid = validateForm();

if ( valid === true ) {
}
```

If I console.log the valid variable, it returns the following:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: true
```

Within my if statement, I am trying to check whether the promise value is true, however I don't know how to gain access to this :/ Could anyone please advise how to check this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: You can either do `await promise()` or use `promise().then()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it either with `.then` or `await`.

```
let valid = validateForm();

valid.then(function(valid) {
 if (valid) {

 }
})
```

```
async function submit () {
  const valid = await validateForm();

  if (valid) {

  }
}
``
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `then` or `await`:

```js
function promiseExample  (){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> resolve("hello world"))
}

(async ()  => {

    //with then
    promiseExample()
       .then(data => console.log('with then: ', data))
       
    //with await
    var data = await promiseExample()
    console.log('with await: ', data);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to believe a simple google search didn't give you an answer for this but here goes:

```
validateForm().then(value => console.log(value))
```

or, within an async function:

```
let value = await validateForm();
```