# Access promise value axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to access the promise value from an Axios call from another function.

```
methods: {
    checkItem() {
        const url = "http://api.crossref.org/journals/" + this.editedItem.issn;
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.status);
    },

    save() {
        console.log(this.checkItem());
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the status code to be logged in the console when I call `save()`. At the moment, it's logging the whole promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async/await`.

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#root",

  methods: {
    checkItem() {
      const url = "http://api.crossref.org/journals/" + this.editedItem.issn;
      return axios.get(url).then(response => response.status);
    }
  },
  async save() {
    console.log(await this.checkItem());
  }
});
</script>
```

Or using `Promise`:

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#root",

  methods: {
    checkItem() {
      const url = "http://api.crossref.org/journals/" + this.editedItem.issn;
      return axios.get(url).then(response => response.status);
    }
  },
  save() {
    this.checkItem().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your save() function to the following:

```
async save() {
  const response = await this.checkItem()
  console.log(response);
  // The status code is likely in something like response.status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.checkItem().then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```