# How to access values of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm writing a comment system built with two databases: one contains the text and the ID of the commenter, which then is used to access the second database to retrieve & dynamically display the poster's profile information (pfp and display name) for each comment they've submitted.

The function inside the `useEffect()` hook returns an array of Promises. I've been trying to figure out ways to access values inside these Promises but so far to no avail. I know that `.then()` exists specifically for this purpose but I don't understand how and where to apply it properly in this case.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'

export const Comments = () => {

    const [cred, setCred] = useState('')
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('')
    const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {

// grab the database containing poster ID 
// & text of each single comment by it's name and then map over it

        firebase.getData('text&ID').onSnapshot(snapshot => setAllComments([...snapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {

// using the poster ID, 
// access the 'users' DB that contains the avatar & name fields

            let comment = doc.data().content
            let poster = await firebase.getData('users').doc(doc.data().posterID).get()
            let name = poster.data().name
            let avatar = poster.data().avatar

// returning an object of all the data we want to display for each comment

            return ({
                name: name,
                avatar: avatar,
                comment: comment
            })
        })]))

// if user exists, set state to their credentials

        firebase.isInitialized().then(val => setCred(val))       
    }, [])

    return allComments && <Fragment>

// submit the comment to the text&DB collection with text, poster ID and text 

        {cred && <form onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            firebase.addComment('text&ID', cred.uid, comment).then(console.log('comment sent!')).then(setComment(''))
        }}>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={comment}
                name="text"
                placeholder="comment..."
                onChange={e => { setComment(e.target.value) }}
                required
            />
            <br />
            <button >Post</button>
        </form>}
        <ul>

// the plan was to map over allComments 
// and return an <li> with all the display info
// but logging to console displays THE array of Promises
// that I want to access

            {console.log(allComments)}
        </ul>
    </Fragment>
}
```

Any and all input is highly welcome.

Here's the console.log output:

```
[Promise]
   0: Promise
      __proto__: Promise
         [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
         [[PromiseValue]]: Object
            avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/v4ImnVE.jpg"
            comment: "no halo"
            name: "polnareff"
         __proto__: Object
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Hi, not sure I'm going to explain this well. You are right, where your console.log is you will need to resolve the promise ".then()" and ".map" the result. I get this wrong waaay too many times myself. Please add to your post the console.log output and I will write up some code to help you resolve it.

Comment: @Francois edited in the contents of console.log output. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: I suggest looking at promise.all()  It basically takes in a array of promises.  `Promise.all([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3])
 .then(result) => {
   console.log(result)
 })
 .catch(error => console.log(`Error in promises ${error}`))` it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Here is a blog post that I found explaining it https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/

Comment: If this gives you the correct output just replace the console.log with ` result.map(item => {<li>{item.comment}</li>})` etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: @Francois this worked, thanks a TON. At first i got the "Objects are not valid as a React child" error but all it took to fix was to simply reintegrate your solution into the useEffect() and now it's working like a clock. A million thanks!

Comment: @VahidAl saw your comment only after I was already done, was a useful read still, thanks!

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Please mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) represents an `asynchronous function` and actually returns a `Promise` in order to be notified when all the code inside the function has been executed.

So in you code `[...snapshot.docs.map(async ...)]` will return an array of `Promise`. By the way, you don't need to use the destructuring operator `...`, you could directly use `snapshot.docs.map` which will return a new array.

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until the resolution of all the promises, then update your state variable `allComments`.

Here is the code of your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {

  firebase.getData('text&ID').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const commentPromises = snapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
      const {posterId} = doc.data();
      const poster = await firebase.getData('users').doc(posterID).get();
      const {avatar, name, content: comment} = poster.data()

      return {name, avatar, comment};
    });

    Promise.all(commentPromises)
      .then(setAllComments)
      .catch(...);
  });

  firebase.isInitialized()
    .then(val => setCred(val))
    .catch(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved from comments to answer as it proved to answer the question.

I suggest looking at promise.all()

It basically takes in a array of promises.

`Promise.all([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3]) 
 .then(result) => { console.log(result) }) 
 .catch(error => console.log(Error in promises ${error}))`

it might be what you are looking for.

If this gives you the correct output just replace the console.log with `result.map(item => {<li>{item.comment}</li>})` etc.