# Assign return value of promise to an external variable in react

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, es6-promise, ionic-react

I hope your are healthy and well.
I am developing a simple mobile application using ionic and react. I am using sql database and for this purpose I created Api's for user registration and login. Whenever a user login, app stores user session using local Storage. [Code for storing session]

```
Storage.set({
  key: 'currentUser',
  value: username
});
```

No the problem is this:  [Code for retrieving stored values]

```
let session;
Storage.get({ key: 'currentUser' })
.then(p1 => {
  const p2 = p1.value;
  const p3 = p2.replace(/"/g, "");
  session = p3;

});

console.log(session) //This gives 'undefined'
```

Here variable (p3) contains actual username. But when I assign its value to session variable. The session variable becomes undefined. I don't know how to get session value out of this function. Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't. The code wrapped in `then()` is executed asynchronously, meaning you don't know what is executed first: `session = p3` or `console.log(session)`.
Maybe this queestion will help?
[How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: So what should be the best approach to store and retrieve sessions in ionic ?

Comment: Are you using react?

Comment: Yes I am using react with ionic (6.1)

Comment: You need to manage state for your app somehow. Maybe put this code in a react component and use useState hook to store state? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is an asynchronous language. Here your request will take some time before arriving and that's why javacript is going to ignore the function `then()`. You can see this process using the `setTimeout` function that emulate your API call:

```js
let session;

setTimeout(() => {
  // This will be executed after 500ms but javascript go ahead and execute the other console log
  session = 'test';
  console.log(session);
}, 500);

console.log(session) // Is executed first
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way of storing and retrieving sessions in ionic?

Comment: @AwaisKhalid Not a problem ;) if it was useful can you please `upvote` my answer ?