# Get result of SQL Query in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, sql, react-native, expo

I am developing a mobile application with React Native. I query a database and I retrieve the data with a "SELECT" request.

The problem is that I can't get the result of this request. 
I would like to retrieve the result of this request is stored all the elements in a list variable

Here is the code of the "Select" request:

```
listProduct()
{
    return new Promise((resolve) => 
    {   
        const db = SQLite.openDatabase('database.db')
        db.transaction(
            tx => {
              tx.executeSql('select * from FRIDGE_PRODUCT', [], (trans, result) => {
                let row = result.rows;
                resolve(row)
                return row
              });
            }
          );
    });  
}
```

And there is the call of this function from another script:

```
async function loadproduct() {
    let result = await db.listProduct();
    return result
}

let row = loadproduct()
```

The problem is that if I want to display the row variable in the console I get this:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Whereas if I print the result directly in the function like this:

```
async function loadproduct() {
  let result = await db.listProduct();
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

I get the right result:

```
Object {
  "DATE": "10/10/2020",
  "IDPRODUCT": 1,
  "IMAGEURL": "imageurl",
  "PRODUCTNAME": "orange",
}
```

How can I store the result in a varialbe ?

I try that:
[How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)
but it doesn't help me too much.

Comment: `let row = loadproduct()` row is a Promise. To access the value you can either do `row = await loadproduct()` or use it in a "then" callback: `loadproduct().then(row => doSomething(row))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loadproduct` function is an *asynchronous* function which returns a Promise object. This means it won't be completed immediately, and you'll have to wait for it to finish. When the promise is resolved/finished it will return your results.

Right now you are setting the `row` variable to the Promise object itself, which is why you see `Promise {something}` in the console.

Before getting the results, JavaScript must wait for the SQL query to finish. When it is completed it will run the `then` or `catch` method, depending on if it was successful or not.

You can wait for it to finish using the `then()` function:

`loadproduct().then(row => doSomethingWithRow(row))`

Or if you are already inside an async function you can use the `await` keyword

`let row = await loadproduct()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems to be working. I am not very familiar with the concepts of Promise

Comment: the post finally helped me understand that async behaviour - thx! (y)