# How to get PromiseValue in XMLHttpRequest. JSON

Tags: javascript, json, promise, xmlhttprequest

How to get array that is located on **`PromiseValue`** instead of getting **`Promise {<pending>}`**
While I'm using **`.then(data => console.log(data))`** I'm getting array in console log. 
However, I need to get an array to place it on the html page so I changet code to **`.then(data => data)`** and started to get **`Promise {<pending>}`**

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

function sendRequest(method, url, data = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open(method, url);

        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 400) {
                reject(xhr.response);
            } else {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            reject(xhr.response);
        }

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}

let getData = sendRequest('GET', baseUrl + '/users')
.then(data => data)
.catch(err => console.log(err));

console.log(getData);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to return the value of `data` as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) to complete the promise

When promise returned by `sendRequest` is resolved, it will immediately pass a new promise to `getData` .

```
.then(data => { 
      return data;
})
.catch (err => { 
      console.log(err);
})
```

looks something like this

```
function sendRequest(s){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       resolve(s) ; 
  });
}

let getData = sendRequest("test")
 .then(value => {
    return value;
})

getData.then(value => {
    console.log( value);
    //access value 
})
```

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Answer (score -1):

`sendRequest()` will execute async. This means that the script continues, even though the data is not loaded. So the last line `console.log(getData)` will already happen before any of the data is loaded.

This is what promises can be used for:

```
sendRequest('GET', baseUrl + '/users')
    .then(function(data){
        // The response can only be processed in the .then part. 
        // You can, however, call other functions with the fetched data
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Another option would be to use async and await. But this does not work in older browsers.

```
function async sendRequest(method, url, data = null) {
// your current xhr code
}

let getData = await sendRequest('GET', baseUrl + '/users');
console.log(getData);
```