# Javascript: How to set value of variable from callback?

Tags: javascript

Consider this scenario:

```
function myfunc() {
   var total = 0;
   const [ hooka, setHooka ] = useState([]);
   const fetchData = () => {
      api.get().then((data) => {
         total = data.total;
         setHooka(data.value);
      }
   }
   return (
       <h1>{total}</h1>
   );
}
```

But the total inside the callback scope is different to the one defined in `myfunc` scope.

How can I set value of `total` in **myfunc scope** within the callback?

PS: It is a react hook in actual. Thank you TJ Crowder for the comment. And I've used total = data before a useState trigger method. I can use total as a hook also. But Doesn't creating more hooks slow down rendering in react or what?

Comment: I believe that you are logging the total count, before the total count value assigned from the API.

Comment: Of course its different, you set the value to be the data. What is the problem or question here?

Comment: How can I reference to `total` from **myfunc scope** inside the callback?

Comment: Except the case that the api returns `0`, `total` will of course be changed. The code is doing exactly what you told him to do.

Comment: The problem isn't that the scope is different (your fulfillment handler closes over `total` just fine), the problem is *timing*: `myfunc` has already returned before your fulfillment handler runs. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise) for how to get the value from a promise, and the other two for general async stuff.

Comment: Nice explaination T.J Crowder. I got it. But it is acutally a React Hook. and There is a render method at the bottom :D