# How to access an async function object from console?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    window.chat = Chat();
});
Chat = async function() {
    this.hello = "world";
    // more code
}
```

when I type in chat in the console, I got

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

When I type chat.hello, I got undefined error

How can I get or access chat.hello from the debug console ?

I also tried

```
$(document).ready(async ()=> {
    window.chat = await Chat(); // this is NEVER called 
});
```

Comment: There are _so many_ questions about resolving promises, did you do any research?

Comment: yes of course: I use async, await very often. I just cannot solve it.

Comment: Well in this case you _didn't_ await it, maybe that's the problem? If you're familiar with promises it's unclear why you thought this might work.

Comment: Yes I did as well : $(document).ready(async ()=> {
 window.chat = await Chat();
});

Comment: And what happened when you did so? There's absolutely no point showing the first version because _of course_ you get a promise object.

Comment: Nothing: you have no chat object at all in console.

Comment: $(document).ready(async () : this infact is never called.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with that code:

1. `this` within the call to `Chat` will either be `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object (in loose mode), so `this.hello = "world"` will either fail (in strict mode) or add a property to the global object.
2. There's no `Chat.hello` property. `Chat` is a function object. You could put a `hello` property on it (`Chat.hello = x`), but that would be an unusual thing to do.
3. It's correct that you see a promise when you look at `chat`. `async` functions return promises, and you're creating the `chat` property by assigning it the result of calling an `async` function. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise) for how to use the value from a promise.

You could make `Chat` a constructor function and call it via `new`. `async` functions can't be constructor functions, though, so you'd probably want to make the `async` part a method on the returned object.