# Trying to get thumbnail of vimeo video

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch

I have written this script for getting thumbnail from vimeo. But getting this result as promise Object. Actually, I want this result a thumbnail.

```
 let url ='https://vimeo.com/535319285';
const getVimeoThumbnail =  (url) => {
    if (url) {
        var video_id, thumbnail, result;
        if (url.match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/)) {
            video_id = url.split('/')[3];
        }
        else if (url.match(/^vimeo.com\/channels\/[\d\w]+#[0-9]+/)) {
            video_id = url.split('#')[1];
        }
        else if (url.match(/vimeo.com\/groups\/[\d\w]+\/videos\/[0-9]+/)) {
            video_id = url.split('/')[4];
        }
        else if (url.match(/player.vimeo.com\/video\/[0-9]+/)) {
            video_id = url.split('/')[2];
        }
            result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/' + video_id)
                    .then(response => {
                        response.json().then((jsonData) => {
                            thumbnail = jsonData.thumbnail_url;
                             resolve(thumbnail);
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.error(error);
                             reject(false);
                        })
                    });
            });
          
             console.log("Result ::", result);
             return result;
       
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You get the thumbnail by using the promise. Details in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)'s answers.

Comment: just add `return` before `new...` keyword : 

`result = return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: @DhavalDarji can you write some more details about what u are trying to say.

Comment: `result = return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`
Compare this with your existing code line, you'll see the `return` keyword in my statement. @DheerajKumar

Comment: @DhavalDarji I have added code this way still getting same result : return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/' + video_id)
                .then(response => {
                    response.json().then((jsonData) => {
                        thumbnail = jsonData.thumbnail_url;
                        resolve(thumbnail);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error);
                        reject(false);
                    })
                });
        });

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am following the link that you have shared. But still could not be able to get desired result.

Comment: @DheerajKumar - See also [the other question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). It doesn't matter how many `.then`s you add. You can't use the result before you have it, which means you can't **return** it from your function. You have to return the promise, and have the code using your function hook the fulfillment of that promise and *then* use the result.