# Promise stuck on pending Reactjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

Why is my promise still pending. I have modal that has a form submit inside of it. I am trying to return the base64 string of the CSV file. this seems to return what i want but it gets stuck on pending

```
    const convertBase64 = (file: any) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
                reject(error);
            };
        });
    };
const handleFileRead = (file: File) : string | null => {
        const base64 = convertBase64(file).then(
            ret => {
                return ret;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                return null;
            });
        console.log("handleFileRead after conversion:", base64);
        return null;
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390)

Comment: You're not `await`ing the `Promise` returned by `Promise.then` before logging it. You're also returning `null` no matter what, you probably want to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `await` the `convertBase64 function` when you call it.
because the `console.log` will run before the `.then`.

and to await the `convertBase64 function`, you'll have to add the `async` keyword before defining the `convertBase64 function`.