# I am stuck with Promise { <pending> } in helper function in ejs file

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

Below is my helper function

```
async function getPriorityList(operatorId) {
  let result = await Api.getApisDetail(operatorId);
  
  return result;

};
```

and below is my modal function

```
static getApisDetail(operatorId) {
    return db.query(
      `select id, api_name, api_type,(select priority from api_switching where api_switching.api_id=api_master.id and operator_id=${operatorId}) as priority,(select isActive from api_switching where  api_switching.api_id=api_master.id and operator_id=${operatorId}) as isActive from api_master where api_type='Recharge' order by api_name asc`
    );
  }
```

Comment: OK but what is the problem? Where do you get the unexpected result? Did you forget to `await` the `getPriorityList` function maybe? (Note that `async: true` must be set in the EJS configuration for this to be supported.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: Actually i am new to nodejs, so do not know how to configure EJS with async:true, where to put async:true exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.