# how to access the ReadableStream inside of the body of the Promise response

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps

I have an mp3 file that I am caching as such:

```
const request = URL_TO_MY_MP3_FILE
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
   cache.add(request);
});
```

I can see that the mp3 file is being cached in the Application tab:
[image]

By the way, how do I ensure that file is cached as `audio/mp3` and not `audio/mpeg`?

Later on, I would like to retrieve the mp3 file from cache so I can play it in the browser:

```
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
     const response = cache.match(request);
     console.log(request, response);
     this.audio = new Audio(response.body);
})
```

[image]

My first question is how to access the ReadableStream inside of the body of the Promise response. Unfortunately, `response.body` is equal to `undefined` and I don't understand how to access the mp3 file otherwise.

Secondly, how do I ensure that file is cached as `audio/mp3` and not `audio/mpeg`?

Comment: This answered my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

```
caches.open("my-cache").then(cache => {
     const response = cache.match(request);
     console.log(request, response);
     response.then(function(result) {
        this.audio = new Audio(response.body);
     }.bind(this), false);
})
```