# Firebase returning Promise{<pending>} after using .then

Tags: firebase, promise

```
const chatdb = db.collection("users").get();
chatdb.then((snapshot) => {
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    if (doc.data().email == userEmail) {
      return { name: doc.data().name, image: doc.data().image };
    }
  });
});
console.log(chatdb);
```

Here, `chatdb` is returning `Promise{<pending>}`, I dont know why, I am just learning the concept of promises and I tried many ways to return the object but everytime it returned as a promise.

I just need to log the object that I returned in the `map` function

[How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise) this doesn't helps

Comment: You cannot get anything else right now but a promise for the future value. You must do the logging later, when the value is available - so just move the `console.log` statement inside the `then` callback

Comment: @Bergi yeah I got the value in log statment but I want it to be reusable for assigning values

Comment: No you don't. You put all code using it in the `then` callback. What else do you need it for other than logging?

Comment: @Bergi Do you have a solution ?

Comment: The solution is to put the code that needs the "assigned values" inside the callback. If you need help with that, please [edit] your question to show that code, and explain why you think you can't put it inside the callback.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, just didn't got that earlier