# return the answer to another promise file

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have an isolated scene. And there is a promise in a separate file. But my scene does not want to wait for an answer. And continue to work. And continues to run, how do I make it wait for an answer, and continued to work

file: a

```
async function apiExchangerate(country, amount) {    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios.get(``, {
            headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" },
            }).then(
            (response) => {
                var result = String(response.data.result).replace(/\..*/, '');
                console.log('Processing Request');
                resolve(result);
            },
                (error) => {
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
}

module.exports = apiExchangerate
```

file: b

```
let request_currency = await apiExchangerate(country,amount) // you have to wait for a response, and then continue the work
```

I want my function to wait for a response and continue executing the script. On the Internet, I have not found an answer to my question.

P.s it doesn't work - [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: If you already know that your attempt is another case of the _"explicit promise construction anitpattern"_, then why do you add the link with a _"it doesn't work"_ comment (that doesn't explain anything) instead of fixing the anti-pattern?

Comment: Do you see the `console.log('Processing Request');` run? If not, the problem is with whatever endpoint you're making your request to not responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrapping Promises in Promises for no real reason.  One of the reasons *why* this is an anti-pattern is because it's *very easy* to get confused by that and to mis-handle resolving/rejecting those Promises.

(My *guess* is that somewhere you're returning a Promise which resolves to... a Promise.  And you're not double-awaiting it so you never resolve the actual Promise.)

Don't over-design it.  Simplify the function.  `axios.get` *already* returns a Promise, and the function is *already* `async`, use those:

```
async function apiExchangerate(country, amount) {
  let response = await axios.get(``, {  headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } });
  let result = String(response.data.result).replace(/\..*/, '');
  console.log('Processing Request');
  return result;
}
```

Then what you have is a simple `async` function which will internally `await` its own operations.  And you can `await` that function:

```
let request_currency = await apiExchangerate(country, amount);
```

Comment: I read that with promis, you can wait for an answer, and then continue the script. But my script still does not wait for an answer and continues to work :(

Comment: @user20839242: When you over-engineer it in the way you have, one of the risks is that you have a Promise which returns a Promise which returns a value.  And you only await the “outer” Promise.  You’ll need to debug to observe what’s happening, but the problem becomes moot if you avoid such anti-patterns and simplify.  Simple code is easier to understand, debug, and support.

Comment: I get it. But how do I wait for an answer and get on with my work? (so that my script stops for the response time)

Comment: @user20839242: By using `await` or a callback.  But when you start wrapping Promises in Promises then you need to start wrapping awaits in awaits, or callbacks in callbacks.  And when you *mix* awaits and callbacks, it gets that much worse.  This is exactly why these are anti-patterns to be avoided.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think it's possible to wrap a promise in a promise, eg: `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1)).then(console.log)` logs 1, not `Promise<1>`, so I don't think the need for double-awaiting here would be needed.

Comment: @NickParsons: Interesting.  Admittedly I hadn't explicitly tested the guess part.  Though of course the OP shouldn't need to worry about it in the first place by just simplifying.

Comment: I mean, there's no way I can wait for an answer and keep working? 

Comment: @user20839242: You keep asking this, and it's unclear what you're really talking about.  To "wait for an answer" you [await the Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390/328193) (either with the `await` keyword or a `.then()` callback).  That's it.  That's *the entirety* of it.  Whatever you've over-complicated beyond that, don't over-complicate it.  At this point you're essentially saying, "Okay, I get that I need to use `await` to wait for the Promise... but how do I wait for the Promise?"