# Trying to call a function inside a table but it returns a promise

Tags: javascript

```
let data = [223, 34, 456, 56, 67];

function getDataFromApi(paramfromTableCell){
let postData = {data : paramfromTableCell}
   let result = apiResponse(url, 'post', postData).catch((err => console.log(err)))
   return result;
}

data.map((value)=>{
 return(
       <th>{getDataFromApi(value)}</th>
 )
})
```

Calling a function inside table cell but it's returning a promise. On calling a function it takes a parameter and return the name as per number but it returning promise. Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Can you share the apiResponse function? Most likely it is returning a promise which you are then storing in result and returning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: Make your function `async`, then you can use `await apiResponse(...)`

Comment: @SanchitAgarwal const apiResponse = async (url, method = "get", formData = {}) => {
  try {
    return await axiosInstance({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Token: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
      data: formData,
    });
  }

Comment: @Barmar is right, you need to await the result from apiResponse, and need to convert the getDataFromApi function to an async once.

Comment: is this react?, maybe u need to use states. etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you using react. You need to save your responses into a react state for that.

Here is a example code how it should look like (not tested):

```
let data = [223, 34, 456, 56, 67];
const [responses, setResponses]  = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const getAllResponses = () => Promise.all(
       data.map(val =>  getDataFromApi(val))
   );

   getAllResponses().then(responses => setResponses(responses));
}, [data])

function getDataFromApi(paramfromTableCell){
    let postData = {data : paramfromTableCell}
    return apiResponse(url, 'post', postData).catch((err => console.log(err)))
}

responses.map((value)=>{
 return(
       <th>{value}</th>
 )
})
```

Comment: it's working fine. but useEffect gets into infinite loop. calling API(getDataFromApi()) again and again.

Comment: @devReact then your data array is changing again and again, maybe wrap your data into a store too :)

Comment: Actually, the let data = [223, 34, 456, 56, 67]. I am getting from a function. Is there any way to update dependency because if I take function as a dependency it again goes into infinite loop

Comment: you need to `useMemo` to remember the array. so it is not always a new array on every render

Answer (score -1):

You have to `await` the promise to get the result.  Otherwise you will just get the promise. So add `async` to your map function and then use `await`:

```
data.map(async (value)=>{
  return(<th>{await getDataFromApi(value)}</th>
)
```