# Cannot figure out how to use Promise to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using an async function that awaits a GraphQL call.  The GraphQL call returns a Promise that does contain the data I want. However, I'm unable to figure out a way to access it.

Here is the code:

```
export async function getModel() {
    try {
        const router = useRouter()
        const {id} = router.query
        console.log("id="+id)
        const res = await API.graphql({
            query: queries.getYawaraModel,
            variables: {id: id}
        })

        return (
            res
        )
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("my error:"+e)
    }
}

export default function Detail({props}) {
    const technique = getModel()
    console.log('technique', technique)
    return <TechniqueListCard
        Description={technique?.Description}
        Technique={technique?.Name}
    />;
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the console log proving the payload data has been returned:
[image]

How do I access the contents of the returned Promise?

Comment: Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Those are similar, but not the same.  There isn't an explicit call to a Promise in the example code. The question is how would that be introduced?

Comment: What do you mean _"an explicit call to a Promise"_ - what do you think `API.graphql` returns, and if _not_ a promise why do you `await` it? And `async` functions **always** return promises, so what's `getModel()` if not an explicit call to a promise? Yes, it's the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK. So a promise is returned on an async call. Got it. Then how is the promise used to access the payload information.  What's the construct?

Comment: `const technique = await getModel()`, but in an async function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `await` the getModel function.

```
export default async function Detail({props}) {
    const technique = await getModel()
    console.log('technique', technique)
    return <TechniqueListCard
        Description={technique?.Description}
        Technique={technique?.Name}
    />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried it. But I get a react error on build :(. The error is `Error: Minified React error #31;`