# How to get the data from the api call by using vue js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I did try to call the api

```
export const users = {
list: () => http.get('users').then(r => r.data),
```

`console.log( users.list());` and in the console I did get such result.
`Promise {<pending>} [[Prototype]] :  Promise [[PromiseState]] :  "fulfilled" [[PromiseResult]] :  Object data :  (14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] [[Prototype]] :  Object` 
And I have question hot to get result the data from it like count of item or another from 'Object data' for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-can-i-access-the-value-of-a-promise)

Comment: Maybe you are right, but when I tried this method I did get this result 'async () => {
            let result = await _http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["users"].list();
            return result;
        }'

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a result. (It seems to be a completely useless function that does nothing except call a function and return its return value).

Comment: I understand you, so what should I do for call this function and get data from it?

Comment: `list().then(data => { /* your data is available here */ })`

Comment: Thank you! How do I get this data from this {} to like console log, because I did something like this one let w= users.list().then(data => { data.length })
    console.log(1,w);, 
And did get like this one Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
undefined

Comment: `list().then(data => { /* your data is available here */ console.log(data); }); /* not here */`

Comment: You should probably read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I have a last quetion, how do I get this data, to like another variable or outside those brackets {}?

Comment: You should definitely read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Thank you! I will read it and try the answers from this question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

accessing the data property using dot notation

```
users.list().then(response => {
  console.log(response.data); // get entire array of data
  console.log(response.data.length); // get count of items in the array
  // get specific item or property using array indexing or dot notation:
  console.log(response.data[0]); // get first item in the array
  console.log(response.data[0].name); // get name property of the first item
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err); // handle any errors during the api call
});
```

access the resolved value of the promise via `.then()`, the resolved value is the response object

Comment: How to get the data from it? Like I want to add this response.data.length to a HTML object?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try like this:

```html
async fetchUsers() {
      try {
        const response = await users.list();
        this.userList = response;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      }
    },
```

If you have users module then import it first at imports section!

Comment: How do I call this function?

Comment: You need to call it at mouted,
mounted(){
this.fetchUsers()
}

Comment: And how get data like this.userList from this function?

Comment: I did try it but have just promise

Comment: Declare an array in data section 
userList:[]

add console.log(this.userList,":::userlist)