# How can I retrieve results from a MySQL query in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql2

I have just started working with Node.js and need to retrieve some data from a database. That has thrown me into the world of promises and callbacks, which I having difficulty getting to work.

I am creating a connection pool, which works fine:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
var database = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "db"
});
```

Then my research has suggested that the following code should wrap the resolved database query into a function. This seems to work:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM table;";
async function getResult(){
    const res = database.query(query);
    return res[0];
};
```

Finally, I want to consume the result and use it in the remaining program. However, this just returns an unresolved promise:

```
var result = getResult(); // This should be available to the global scope.
console.log(result); // Promise { <pending> }
```

I don't understand how to resolve the promise and actually get the data I need.

If I try to add an `await` in the function, I get an error:

```
async function getResult(){
    const res = await database.query(query);
    return res[0]; // ERROR
};
```

If I try to add an `await` to the function output, I also get an error:

```
var result = await getResult(); // ERROR
```

I feel there should be a simple step that I am missing.

EDIT:
The errors I get are; for the `await` *in* the function:

> You have tried to call .then(), .catch(), or invoked await on the
> result of query that is not a promise, which is a programming error.
> Try calling con.promise().query(), or require('mysql2/promise')
> instead of 'mysql2' for a promise-compatible version of the query
> interface. To learn how to use async/await or Promises check out
> documentation at
> https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs#using-promise-wrapper, or
> the mysql2 documentation at
> https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs/documentation/promise-wrapper
> /var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/query.js:43
> throw new Error(err);
> ^
>
> Error: You have tried to call .then(), .catch(), or invoked await on
> the result of query that is not a promise, which is a programming
> error. Try calling con.promise().query(), or require('mysql2/promise')
> instead of 'mysql2' for a promise-compatible version of the query
> interface. To learn how to use async/await or Promises check out
> documentation at
> https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs#using-promise-wrapper, or
> the mysql2 documentation at
> https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs/documentation/promise-wrapper
> at Query.then (/var/www/html/nodejs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/query.js:43:11)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
>
> Node.js v18.17.1

and for the `await` *outside* the function:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level
> bodies of modules
> at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
>
> Node.js v18.17.1

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: Yes, `getResult()` returns a promise, and you must wait for the result. There's no way around this.

Comment: It is not clear to me though _how_ I should wait for the result. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390 for the general answer. Both the `await`s you have placed seem appropriate. But unless you tell us what error they "caused" (exposed), we can't tell you what the problem is or how to fix it.

Comment: I just edited the OP with error details (the error text is a bit too long for a comment).

Comment: Thanks for the update. For the first error, the message is quite clear on what you need to change. For the second, you must place your `await getResult()` call inside an `async function`, where were you trying to use it?

Comment: So the bit i missed in my 'minimal' example, is that this code runs inside a WebSockets server. That may be complicating things. With the help of Amit Mishra's answer below, I have come up with a solution, which I will post as an answer below (so I can format it proplerly). This may be too hacky though.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a MySQL database with a connection pool, and you want to perform a query and retrieve the results.

Please see:

**1. Create a Database Connection Pool:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const database = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "db"
});
```

**2. Define a Function to Get Results:**

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM table;";

async function getResult() {
    // Use 'await' to wait for the query to complete
    const [rows, fields] = await database.promise().query(query);
    return rows;  // Return the result
}
```

**3. Call the Function in an Async Context:**

```
async function main() {
    // Use 'await' when calling the function to get the actual result
    var result = await getResult();
    console.log(result);  // Log the result
}

// Call the main function to start the process
main();
```

This is working for me. Please let me know, if it's working as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Because my code is running inside a WebSockets server (a detail not in my OP, but is perhaps relevant), I am unsure how to bubble up the asynchronous functions to the calling WebSockets functions.

With help of Amit Mishra's answer, I have come up with a solution that seems to work in my situation though. I am just sending the result of the database query through the socket from *inside* the async function containing the query.

This achieves my goal, but seems like it may be a hack that should not be the accepted answer - I'd love to know why Node.js gurus might think this is a bad idea.

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const server = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});

var database = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "db"
});

server.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(rawMessage){

        !async function(){
        
            var query = "SELECT * FROM table;";
            var [rows, fields] = await database.promise().query(query);

            socket.send(rows); // Actually the database response is formatted into a JSON object before sending.
        }();

    });
});
```

Comment: You might not need that IIFE, you can just mark the `function` that you are passing to `socket.on('message', …)` as `async`

Comment: Yup. You are right, that is more elegant. ```socket.on('message', async function(rawMessage){...``` and just remove the IIFE. It works great.